# Data structure(s) good for calc'ing distances between changing coordinates (~1sec)

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, coordinates

Basically I'm working with the X,Y,Z coordinates (and other data) of up to 32 racers.

I want to calculate the closing speed between each, to try and figure out whether or not something *interesting* may be about to happen.

I'm aware that doing all 32 is ridiculous, so I've setup a grid system and using that to only calculate between "near" vehicles, and it mostly works.

But I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

As the X,Y,Z coords change about every second I'd dismissed a kd-tree and other data structures. However I'm not "classically" trained - no compsci degree schooling - so I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Do they move at similar speeds? You could try a KD-tree in the coordinate frame of Racer #1, so you only need to update the KD-tree when the position relative to Racer #1 changes significantly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't guarantee that they'll all be moving at a similar speed, as the vehicles might be a different class :( I'll give it a go and see if it helps tho - thanks artoonie :)